# Why is the color of the gridview row not changing?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

When I click on a row of gridview, I want its color to change. 
In C# I have the following:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  if (!Page.IsPostBack) {
    GridView1.DataBind();
  }
}

protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e) {
  e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", "ChangeRowColor('"+e.Row.ClientID +" ')");
}
```

and in JavaScript I have this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ChangeRowColor(row) {
        //change the color of the current row to light yellow
        document.getElementById(row).style.backgroundColor = "#ffffda";
    }
</script>
```

I checked that the id of the gridview row that is sent to JavaScript is true, but the color of that row is not changing! How can I make that happen?

Comment: does the code get hit? maybe just a style-problem ...

Comment: You will need to apply the style to the cells, not to the row. Ie to the `<td>`s not the `<tr>`

Comment: @El Ronnoco: this is not true ... you can change the background via the row!

Comment: @Andreas I stand corrected! I'm sure I've had difficulty setting styles of rows before?

Comment: @ElRonnoco: there you go http://jsfiddle.net/bNcyc/

Comment: If you want a jQuery solution, you your mention it somewhere in your question.

Comment: @Andreas thanks, I'd already proved it to myself in JsFiddle :) I think I once had problems setting `opacity` at `tr` level and had to iterate `td`s instead...

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Change it to use jQuery:

**Updated** thanks to [@ocanals](https://stackoverflow.com/users/603127/ocanal) comment. (note the inclusion of "#"+)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function ChangeRowColor(row) {
    $("#"+row).css("backgroundColor","#ffffda");
  }
</script>
```

Comment: c'mon on ... he's asking for plain javascript - why bother with jquery?

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair: Check the tags, one is jQuery!

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair + that's not correct also. you can not handle element by $(row), correct one is $("#"+row).css("backgroundColor","#ffffda");

Comment: @ocanal: fair play buddy, wasnt 100% sure what value was coming across from his c#, i'll update my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Check the background style of the `TD`s.  It is better to use a class instead of inline so that the `TD`s can inherit and change:

```
<style> 
  tr.clicked {background-color: ffffda;} 
  tr.clicked td{ background: #fffda; }      
</style>  

 function ChangeRowColor(row) {
    document.getElementById(row).className= "clicked";     
 }
```

Comment: This is a much better solution. Update the class name, then you can control the styles of the row's children easily. So if changing the tr background colour isnt working, then change the cell background color by using tr.clicked td{ background: #fffda; }

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @Tim, added your CSS suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
             e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", "this.style.backgroundColor='#ffffda'");

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

All these are nice answers, but what I would do (since you ARE using javascript anyway) is "jqueryfy" this to the max :P

Include your jquery script file in the head:

```
<script src="local path or cdn path"></script>
```

Then using some sort of identifier on your table rows (using a class name in this example and since you are using a GridView Control)

```
<RowStyle CssClass="rowstyle bg-changer" />
<AlternativeRowStyle CssClass="altrowstyle bg-changer" />
```

Then you can just create your jQuery function to manage the background colour change

```
$(function(){
    $('.bg-changer').click(function(){
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    });
});
```

In your stylesheet, you then have great control over the styles of `.bg-changer`, `.bg-changer .selected` AND your two row styles `rowstyle` and `altrowstyle` e.g

```
.rowstyle .selected{ background: red; }
.altrowstyle .selected{ background: blue; }
```

If you wanted to take it a step further you could just toggle the selected class

```
$(this).toggleClass('selected');
```

So that you can select and deselect a row.